# Why I can't run any commands as administrator using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS WSL2 on Windows 10

Tags: terminal, wsl2, ubuntu-22.04

So I have question about WSL2 , I am running it on windows, and can't run any commands as administrator. I have two accounts one administrator and one regular, on regular one everything works perfectly but when I run WSL2 as Admin it's not working...

Also want to know is the good practice to run WSL2 as Admin or it's fine to run it on regular account without Admins rights...
when I try to run for example this command to update system it gives me this output:

```
 sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
0% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: The reason that command failed, has nothing to do with being ran as an Administrator, your WSL instance was unable to resolve both of those domains. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error) is a question from 11 years ago that explains the real reason. [Here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/937) is a WSL GitHub issue that describes the same problem. In order to answer your question I would need additional information. Do you happen to have McAfee software installed?

Comment: So `apt` *fails* only when using the Ubuntu that is installed in the Administrator account, right?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Yes

Comment: @Ramhound no I don't use additional anti-viruses, just windows defender

Comment: Well, as far as "best practice" goes, at least, [Microsoft recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#installation-issues), *"you should ensure that you aren't accidentally running the built-in Administrator account that comes with Windows."*  WSL is definitely designed to be run as a normal user.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds so yes I was basically trying to do that, I was running WSL2 from the built-in Administrator account. So I should not run it as administrator,right? because when, I run it as normal user it works perfectly...

Comment: @RostoRM In general, it's best not to run it from the Administrator account.  For security reasons alone, I wouldn't do it.  It's likely that the WSL2 DNS resolver is running under the default user account (which is why it works there) but that the one running under the Admin account can't access it for some reason (wrong path, trying to start a different process, etc.).

Comment: @RostoRM - Did you read the links I provided. Did the solutions describe in those linked resolve your issue?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thanks for info...

Comment: @Ramhound yes I read it, but it was different issue... there was DNS problem...

Comment: @RostoRM - Which is what my first comment suggested was the problem